# MySQL LIMIT to not split a group

Tags: mysql

I have a little weird question.
I have 2 tables in my application, **regions** and **schools**. Schools has a column, in which region it is situated.

I want to do a SELECT statement to join these tables together with LIMIT. But LIMIT can't split a group of REGION-SCHOOLS.

**Example**

REGIONS

```
ID  name of region
1   Moravia
2   Czech
```

SCHOOLS

```
ID  region   school
1      1     VSB
2      1     SPS Kratochvilova
3      1     T.G. Masaryka
4      2     ZS Praha
5      2     CVUT
```

And now when I use JOIN to connect these tables together I get

```
region   school
Moravia  VSB
Moravia  SPS Kratochvilova
Moravia  T.G. Masaryka
Czech    ZS Praha
Czech    CVUT
```

But when I use LIMIT 4 to pagination, I have part of region czech on first page, and next part on second page.

Is there some solution how to use LIMIT to not split these groups?

In my case, in one region will be up to 5 schools, maybee sometimes 6, but very rarely.

Comment: What would be the desired behavior, when you list a 6-school region + `LIMIT 4`? Cut that region in half, or list all 6 schools instead?

Comment: This can confuse user. May be a bad pattern. Perhaps each page can contains fixed numer of regions instead fixed number of schools.

Comment: Yes, do the list of 6 regions, even every region has 2 or 5 schools is solution. But how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this should do the trick:

```
select schools.name, 
    regions.name
from schools
join (
        select id, name 
        from regions 
        order by regions.name
        limit 0,2) as regions
    on regions.id = schools.region
```

Comment: Bad thing is, that I need to use instead of `where region = (..` this: `where region IN (`. But then I get error **This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'**

Comment: you should add an "order by" to your solution, because e.g. changes in keys can change it if you leave it up to mysql

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand, what you mean. What can be wrong, when `ORDER BY` statement isn't there?

Comment: it won't be wrong in general, but it is not deterministic. your result set is influenced by the physical data structure, the insert order etc. it could change if you e.g. restore a backup, change your keys from ascending to descending...